# Double integration with a piecewise function gives wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I am attempting to solve a double integral
$$I(t) = \int_0^t dt' \int_0^{t'} dt'' f(t'')$$
of a piecewise function of the type
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{for } 0 \leq t < a \\ -1 & \text{for } t>a\end{cases}$$
with Mathematica. One can easily verify that for $t>a$ this should evaluate to
$$I(t) = \frac12 t (4 a - t) - a^2 $$
However, if I try to solve in Mathematica using

```
Simplify[Integrate[Integrate[Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= ttt < a}, {-1, a <= ttt}}], {ttt, 0, tt}], {tt,0, t}], {t > a > 0}]
```

The result I get is

```
-(1/2) t (-4 a + t)
```

I.e. it is obviously missing the $-a^2$.

I am puzzled why this is happening. Am I simply too stupid to use Mathematica's Piecewise/Integrate function correctly?
If instead of the variable $a$ I plug in a number, say 1, everything seems to evaluate correctly.

Comment: Have you already seen formula 5 [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html), by any chance?

Comment: The command `Integrate[
 Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= ttt < a}, {-1, a <= ttt}}], {tt, 0, t}, {ttt, 0, 
  tt}, Assumptions -> t > a > 0]` performs `1/2 (-2 a^2 + 4 a t - t^2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mathematica 12, your original code returns the warning

> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {0,tt} are real. Adding assumptions may help.

And, indeed, adding the appropriate assumptions does help:

```
Simplify[Integrate[Integrate[
   Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= ttt < a}, {-1, a <= ttt}}], {ttt, 0, tt}, 
   Assumptions -> {tt, 0} \[Element] Reals], {tt, 0, t}], {t > a > 0}]

(* -a^2 + 2 a t - t^2/2 *)
```

I couldn't tell you *why* such assumptions are necessary, but it does seem to give you the correct answer this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I guess I was right about just being too stupid. Strangely, I did not get the warning you are quoting.

Comment: @André: I probably would have been confused too if I hadn't received any error messages.  Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Combining your two sequential evaluations of Integrate into one, from your original code:

```
Integrate[
 Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= tDoublePrime < a}, {-1, tDoublePrime > a}}],
 {tPrime, 0, t},
 {tDoublePrime, 0, tPrime}
]
```

returns a warning:

> `Integrate::pwrl`: Unable to prove that integration limits `{0, t, tPrime}` are real. Adding assumptions may help.

So let's add assumptions as suggested:

```
Assuming[
 {t ∈ Reals, tPrime ∈ Reals},
 Integrate[
   Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= tDoublePrime < a}, {-1, tDoublePrime > a}}],
   {tPrime, 0, t},
   {tDoublePrime, 0, tPrime}
 ]
]
```

[image: piecewise integral with no simplification]

You mentioned that you are particularly interested in the case of $t>a$, so we can include that assumption as well, and see if the output can be simplified:

```
Assuming[
 {t ∈ Reals, tPrime ∈ Reals, t > a},
 Simplify@
   Integrate[
     Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= tDoublePrime < a}, {-1, tDoublePrime > a}}],
     {tPrime, 0, t},
     {tDoublePrime, 0, tPrime}
   ]
]
```

[image: result for t > a]

The result above is equivalent to the one you mentioned for $t>a$.

If you changed the definition of your `Piecewise` function to specifically include that $a>0$ (e.g. `Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= tDoublePrime < a}, {-1, tDoublePrime > a > 0}}]`), then you could further simplify the output.